# OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain error comes with Google Federated Authentication in WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, google-plus, google-oauth, wso2-identity-server

I have created a `SAML SSO service` and used `Google Federated Authentication`.

When I am redirected back to Google and after successful authentication I am getting this error:

> OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain:
>   https://example.com:9446/commonauth

I have already registered a `OAuth client` in Google developer console and registered this redirection url.

When I search the internet I found that, Google closed registration to new OpenID 2.0 clients.  - https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: As a workaround I have enabled the Federated Authenticators >  OAuth2/OpenID Connect Configuration with Google+ client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use the OpenID Connect Authenticator or we need to write our own authenticator to use Google Plus API.